# How to translate "by means of utterance"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, philosophy-terms, neologism

If I in a philosophy paper wish to say that a statement renders itself meaningless/contradictory "in utterance" or "by means of utterance" (i.e. upon being uttered), is there a way to do this? similarly to "ad analysandum".

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how well this would work for a paper written in English, but as far as Latin goes I would use an ablative of means.

An **ablative of means**, like the name suggests, tells the means by which something is accomplished. The noun (the means) is declined into the ablative case, and it does not require any other words to convey its meaning in the sentence.

Let's say you wanted to use *dictum* as your word for utterance; *dicto* is how you would decline it for the ablative case, and the normal ablative of means would say that you need nothing other than this to convey your intended meaning (at least for a Latin sentence).

If you wanted to translate this as "upon being uttered," you would need to use passive voice to convey that meaning. You could use *dictatur*, or perhaps *in* *dictatur*, which means "being uttered."